# Dynamics CRM 2016 modify list of activities views

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I am very new to MS Dynamics. I am using dynamics CRM 2016 and I need to remove, in the activities page, the views about entities that I am not using such as Campaign Response, Campaign Activity, etc.

I do not see them in the list of views of the Activity entity in my solution, so I cannot remove them from there, am I missing something? Is there a way to remove those views?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Its possible. I found the way to do it finally after just 3 days of research.

Open your CRM web in XRM Tool kit (download if not having it)
XRM toolkit access your org using url and login. Assuming you have privilege access.
Load all web resources and scroll down to find "activitypointer_ribbon_home.js" 
Add below lines of code into the file,
finally Save and publish to make it available for all users. Whoa.. it works like charm !!!

```js
hideactivitiesview() // call under onload of xrm page; comes in default script of this file

function hideactivitiesview()
{
  var viewSelector = $('#crmGrid_SavedNewQuerySelector')[0];
  if(viewSelector)
  {
    $(viewSelector).click(function(){
      var _activity = $('#ViewSelector_activity')[0]; //get this id from DOM using F12
      if(_activity)
        $(_activity).hide();
      
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot hide/remove those.

**Reason**: They are not usual views, they are part of System tailored Activity entity family (Activity, Activity Pointer, Activity Party, Custom Activity types, etc).

If you see any Activity entity properties, the checkbox '*Display in Activity Menus*' is checked & disabled. This settings is being used for navigation, views, filters, etc.

Even while creating custom activity, this option is enabled & if you forget to check it, that particular Custom Activity type will be hidden from everywhere wherever you are using its siblings (Email, Fax, etc)

If its unchecked, Even [Associated view](http://deepscrm.blogspot.com/2012/07/custom-activity-display-in-activity.html) will not be showing this activity under it's regarding Parent record, which is failing the main reason why we are using CRM & activity relationship.

In a nutshell, this setting once enabled, cannot be undone. The activity cannot be distinguished/disabled using security role, because all are of same bucket.

[image]

Maybe you can try some unsupported customizations using DOM explorer in javascript & hide it, which I don't recommend. [PowerObjects blog](https://www.powerobjects.com/2014/03/24/what-to-do-with-unwanted-activity-types-in-dynamics-crm/) talk about renaming it to something to avoid users using it & other options.

Comment: I don't get why we cannot remove them, this is very confusing for the end users when their business has nothing to do with that kind of activities, but anyways, thank you for your reply.

Comment: @rox I agree, like I explained its more complex than it looks.. how about renaming it to Z_do_not_use.. may be not user friendly & dirty, but a recommendation to help users to ignore those